# How to Clone/Copy a mongodb database using mongodump on an AWS ECS server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongo-shell, mongodump

I have ssh into an AWS EC2 instance MongoDB database that has a password and username and I need to duplicate the database called admin.
To show that the database exists, first i enter the MongoDB shell by using the command below

```js
mongo --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "*******" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

after entering the mongoshell i can run "show dbs" command and the databases are listed. This is an indication that the password and user are correct.

Now the problem is an auth error when i try to use mongodbdump. Below is the command I use

```js
mongodump  --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "*******" --authenticationDatabase "admin"  --archive="mongodump-admin-db" --db=admin
```

Below is the auth error i get yet I am sure that the credentials are correct

```js
Failed: error creating intents to dump: error counting admin.system.views: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { count: "system.views", lsid: { id: UUID("5e8e1d85-76c7-4a1c-854f-4ea90573d3d9") }, $db: "admin" }
```

As of now, I am using the Mongodump documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/).

Kindly help on on how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the user does not have the correct privileges to read `system.views` on the admin database. `system.views` is created when you create a view on a collection.

In my case, this was not something that had been done intentionally, so deleting the views and dropping collection `system.views` resolved the issue.

To drop `system.views`, I created a role `dropSystemViewsAnyDatabase`, as described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#create-a-role-to-drop-system-views-collection-across-databases).

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "dropSystemViewsAnyDatabase",
     privileges: [
       {
         actions: [ "dropCollection" ],
         resource: { db: "", collection: "system.views" }
       }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Then I assigned this role to a new user, accessed the db with this new user and dropped the collection.

```
db.getCollection("system.views").drop()
```

Afterwards, `mongodump` did not produce any error anymore.